# ¿Cómo ejecuto un comando en segundo plano?

Tags: linux, bash

Tengo una caché que está funcionando sobre Kubernetes y para ver los logs de la misma me tengo que meter en el pod de la caché.

Para obtener los logs tengo que ejecutar `varnishlog -c` y esto me saca una salida en tiempo real del contenido de la caché (en este caso contenido de vídeo) pero yo quiero guardar esa salida en un archivo para poder ver las peticiones que se hicieron en un día atrás.

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo hacer esto? He probado:

```
varnishlog -c > prueba.txt
```

pero necesito que se haga en segundo plano.

Answer (score 1):

Si necesitas que algo se haga en segundo plano con bash puedes añadir el carácter & al final del comando (separado del comando por un espacio).

Usando tu ejemplo:

```
varnishlog -c > prueba.txt &
```

Ejecuta "varnishlog -c > prueba.txt" en segundo plano.

Otro ejemplo:
"ls / > logprueba.log &" guardará el contenido del directorio raíz en el archivo logprueba.log, como tiene & al final esto se ejecutará en segundo plano y mostrando un mensaje cuando se complete la tarea:

```
$ ls / > logprueba.log &
[1] 3625
$ 
[1]+  Hecho                   ls --color=auto / > logprueba.log
$
```

Comment: Añadir solo que si estás accediendo a un servidor remoto, debes combinar el & con el comando `nohup` para que si desconectas el proceso siga funcionando